Entered UK without a stamped leave to enter: How long was I granted entry for?
I am a visa national to the UK and recently got a 6 month multi entrance tourist visa for the UK. My visa remarks state "Duration 180 days."
I entered the UK today through Heathrow Airport, and was given only a regular stamp with no associated Leave to Enter stamp. This is confusing to me as I have some friends who got the same type of visa with same validity, and when they entered the UK they were given an additional stamp saying leave to enter for 14 days. There's also other posts on this site of people with visas being given leave to enters until their return flight.
Is it normal to not receive a leave to enter? What is my approved duration of entry, is it the end date of my visa?

I'm asking specifically in the framing of being able to use my visa to visit Republic of Ireland too, and while I thankfully hadn't planned that on this trip, I'm not sure if I can just plan trips to directly fly to RoI from my country of residence or not (Timatic says I could as long as my leave to enter covers the dates I fly on).
Timatic says that the maximum entry duration I'll be granted by RoI depends on my granted duration of stay.

https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/short-stay-visa-waiver-programme agrees:

Your journey to Ireland must take place within the dates of your permission to be in the UK.



Is it normal to not receive a leave to enter?

Based on my (visa national) partner’s experience over the last 9 years, yes, it is entirely normal. The only stamp he has ever received is the date of arrival/entry stamp, including on his latest 3 1/2 month long visit during which he spent one month in the UK, a week outside the UK (not in his home country), and a further two months in the UK.  On his initial arrival and on his return after the week away, he received the standard arrival/entry stamp each time.

What is my approved duration of entry, is it the end date of my visa?

It is 180 days from each arrival date stamp, or the end date of your visa, whichever comes first.
See the related question here
